# Правильно ли выполнены операции с XOR и OR

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Есть массив `byte [] regs`, в котором содержатся данные, к которым обращаются с помощью `reg1` и `reg2` (предварительно получают для них числовые данные с помощью `Reg1` и `Reg2`).

Операции XOR или OR каждому биту нужно сделать отдельно, а результат оставить в массиве под номером `reg1`

Правильно ли написан код?

```
if (byt == "0x0E")//XOR
{
    reg1 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(Reg1);
    reg2 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(Reg2);
    regs[reg1] = regs[reg1] ^ regs[reg2];
}
if (byt == "0x0F")//OR
{
    reg1 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(Reg1);
    reg2 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(Reg2);
    regs[reg1] = regs[reg1] | regs[reg2];
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info

Comment: А что у вас находится в `Reg1` и `Reg2`?

Comment: @VladD ,  `Reg1` и `Reg2` _char_ типа, они берутся из одной общей строки. Данные в них - обычне числа, вроде "0", "1"..."9" ( для работы с массивом).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден.
Нужно было, чтобы все операции были битовые, без использования `(int) Char.GetNumericValue`. Грубо говоря, мне не нужно было переводить данные в `char` и `string`, затем в `int`, а работать сразу с типом `byte`. В таком случае, дополнительные переменные не нужны и код выходит очень лаконичным:

```
if (byt == "0x0E"){ //XOR
regs[reg1] = (byte)(regs[reg1] ^ regs[reg2]);
}
if (byt == "0x0F"){ // OR
    regs[reg1] = (byte)(regs[reg1] | regs[reg2]);
    }
```

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос и спасибо всем.